# Eclipse 4.2.2 crashes when okPressed on org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.TitleAreaDialog (GTK+2 and GTK+3 )

Tags: eclipse, gtk3, gtk2

On Eclipse 4.2.2 (64 bit Linux), when okPressed on extended org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.TitleAreaDialog ... Eclipse crashes!
Running Eclipse in CLEAN mode and trying a new workspace also did not prevent the crash.

**To summarize the detail below:**

- can GTK be reinstalled
- is there an alternative to GTK - that works!?

Worst case scenario, I can migrate to version 4.4.2 Eclipse however ... it will take a little time and I cannot be sure that same or similar issue exists on that customers server with Eclipse 4.4.2.  Running Eclipse in DEBUG mode did not highlight any additional information.

```
public class TopicDialog  extends TitleAreaDialog {
    //.....
    @Override
    protected void okPressed() {
        super.okPressed();
    }
}
```

Dialog is displayed by code:

```
final TopicDialog d = new TopicDialog(getShell());          
// Launch dialog        
Display.getDefault().syncExec(new Runnable() {              
    @Override
    public void run() {          
        d.open();   
    }
});
```

GTK stacktrace is logged at time of crash - see below.  I have asked the customer to force Eclipse to use GTK +2 (rather than default GTK +3) and ignoring cairoGraphics. So the eclipse.ini contains 2 GTK specific settings:

```
--launcher.GTK_version
2
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.cairoGraphics=false
```

Stacktrace:

```
3XMTHREADINFO "main" J9VMThread:0x0000000040E2F100, j9thread_t:0x00007F04B802DB20, java/lang/Thread:0x0000000000F25540, state:R, prio=6 
3XMJAVALTHREAD (java/lang/Thread getId:0x1, isDaemon:false) 
3XMTHREADINFO1 (native thread ID:0x516B, native priority:0x6, native policy:UNKNOWN) 
3XMTHREADINFO2 (native stack address range from:0x00007F04BF04E000, to:0x00007F04BFA4F000, size:0xA01000) 
3XMHEAPALLOC Heap bytes allocated since last GC cycle=685960 (0xA7788) 
3XMTHREADINFO3 Java callstack: 
4XESTACKTRACE at org/eclipse/swt/internal/gtk/OS._gdk_window_at_pointer(Native Method) 
4XESTACKTRACE at org/eclipse/swt/internal/gtk/OS.gdk_window_at_pointer(OS.java:5271) 
4XESTACKTRACE at org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Display.getCursorControl(Display.java:1413) 
4XESTACKTRACE at org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Control.gtk_leave_notify_event(Control.java:3066) 
4XESTACKTRACE at org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Widget.windowProc(Widget.java:1776(Compiled Code)) 
4XESTACKTRACE at org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Control.windowProc(Control.java:5116(Compiled Code)) 
4XESTACKTRACE at org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Display.windowProc(Display.java:4377(Compiled Code)) 
4XESTACKTRACE at org/eclipse/swt/internal/gtk/OS._gtk_widget_hide(Native Method) 
4XESTACKTRACE at org/eclipse/swt/internal/gtk/OS.gtk_widget_hide(OS.java:13119) 
4XESTACKTRACE at org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Shell.dispose(Shell.java:2306) 
4XESTACKTRACE at org/eclipse/jface/window/Window.close(Window.java:335) 
4XESTACKTRACE at org/eclipse/jface/dialogs/Dialog.close(Dialog.java:979) 
4XESTACKTRACE at org/eclipse/jface/dialogs/Dialog.okPressed(Dialog.java:940)     
4XESTACKTRACE at com/ibm/tivoli/pa/model/ui/dialogs/TopicDialog.okPressed(TopicDialog.java:135)     
4XESTACKTRACE at org/eclipse/jface/dialogs/Dialog.buttonPressed(Dialog.java:472)     
4XESTACKTRACE at org/eclipse/jface/dialogs/Dialog$2.widgetSelected(Dialog.java:624) 
4XESTACKTRACE at org/eclipse/swt/widgets/TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:248)     
4XESTACKTRACE at org/eclipse/swt/widgets/EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84(Compiled Code))     
4XESTACKTRACE at org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1276) 
4XESTACKTRACE at org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3562(Compiled Code)) 
4XESTACKTRACE at org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3186(Compiled Code)) 
4XESTACKTRACE at org/eclipse/jface/window/Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:825) 
4XESTACKTRACE at org/eclipse/jface/window/Window.open(Window.java:801)
```

Comment: Why are you using `syncExec` to open the dialog? If you are on the UI thread this is not needed, if you are not on the UI thread the `TopicDialog` constructor should also be in the `syncExec`

Comment: Thank you for comments - I can review code.                                         I have an additional error after running Eclipse in debug mode:      !ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2015-07-13 21:59:56.362 
!MESSAGE Application error 
!STACK 1 
org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: No more handles [gtk_init_check() failed] 
        at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4387) 
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.createDisplay(Display.java:914) 
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.create(Display.java:900) .......

Comment: Thank you @greg-449 for comments - I can review code - code is in production so ideally want to find cause if issue.  I have an additional error after running Eclipse in **DEBUG** mode:      
**org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: No more handles [gtk_init_check() failed].**  User is running Eclipse via VNC so SSH; Display; X Server issues are not relevant ... also setting environment variable **JAVA_HIGH_ZIPFDS** did not resolve issue.